# Three second countdown in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to have a 3 second countdown display when a level is beat in my game. So this is what I did:

```
-(void) gameSegmentBeat {
    [self pauseSchedulerAndActions];

    // Overlay the game with an opaque background
    CCSprite *opaqueBG = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"background1.png"];
    opaqueBG.position = screenCenter;
    [self addChild:opaqueBG z:10000];

    // These are the 3 labels for the 3 seconds
    CCLabelTTF *three = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"3" fontName:@"Helvetica" fontSize:100];
    three.position = ccp(screenCenter.x, screenCenter.y);
    CCLabelTTF *two = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"2" fontName:@"Helvetica" fontSize:100];
    two.position = ccp(screenCenter.x, screenCenter.y);
    CCLabelTTF *one = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"1" fontName:@"Helvetica" fontSize:100];
    one.position = ccp(screenCenter.x, screenCenter.y);

    // Secondspast is specified in the update method 
    secondspast = 0;
    if (secondspast == 1) {
        [self addChild:three z:10001];
    } else if (secondspast == 2) {
        [self removeChild:three];
        [self addChild:two z:10001];
    } else if (secondspast == 3) {
        [self removeChild:two];
        [self addChild:one z:10001];
    }
}
```

And the update:

```
framespast = 0;

-(void)update:(ccTime)delta {
      framespast++;
      secondspast = framespast / 60;
}
```

I called `gameSegmentBeat` in one of the methods I have not shown above... and I know it is being called because: 1. The `pauseSchedulerAndActions` is working and 2. The `CCSprite *opaqueBG` is being shown.

**Also, something I should add is that if I move `[self addChild:three z:10001];` outside of the if statement that it is currently in, then the label shows up, but as soon as I move back into the if statement, it doesn't work...**

I don't know why, but the labels are not being switched every second and so there is no countdown.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where is gameSegmentBeat called? i'm guessing its being called once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly use timed execution blocks for 1, 2 and 3 second delay in execution:

```
dispatch_time_t countdownTime1 = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(countdownTime1, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

    [self addChild:three z:10001];

});

dispatch_time_t countdownTime2 = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(countdownTime2, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

    [self removeChild:three];
    [self addChild:two z:10001];

});

dispatch_time_t countdownTime3 = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3 * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(countdownTime3, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

    [self removeChild:two];
    [self addChild:one z:10001];

});
```

Comment: Thanks! You not only solved my problem, but you also taught me something new! +1 and accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

your label is not switched as the code for switching the label is not called (at least, it's not visible in the code you shared).

invoke `gameSegmentBeat` from within your update loop

```
-(void)update:(ccTime)delta {
    framespast++;
    secondspast = framespast / 60;

    [self gameSegmentBeat];
}
```

Comment: Yes, I called the label switch, when one of the objects in my game touches another one. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
[self pauseSchedulerAndActions];
```

will prevent the update method from being called. As it says this pauses the scheduler.

To test if update gets called [set a breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/Creating,Disabling,andDeletingBreakpoints/Creating,Disabling,andDeletingBreakpoints.html).

Comment: Do you know another way I could switch labels (or have a countdown) that works with `pauseSchedulerAndActions`? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Few things...

1. function `gameSegmentBeat` is being called once in which the value of secondspast is set to 0 and hence none of the `if-conditions` are met and therefore you dont see any label.
2. function `gameSegmentBeat` calls `pauseSchedulerAndActions` which pauses all scheduled selectors and actions and therefore, your function `update` is not called and therefore the value of secondspast doesnt change. Even if it did change, it wouldnt matter in the above code since gameSegmentBeat is not being called from update.

Now if you must call the pauseSchedulerAndActions you can perhaps do the following:

```
-(void) visit{

    framespast++;
    secondspast = framespast / 60;

    if (secondspast == 1) {
        [self addChild:three z:10001];
    } else if (secondspast == 2) {
        [self removeChild:three];
        [self addChild:two z:10001];
    } else if (secondspast == 3) {
        [self removeChild:two];
        [self addChild:one z:10001];
    }
    [super visit];
}
```